# Undefined reference to class function in Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I am fairly new to Arduino and have recently gotten several VEX robotics 3-wire motors that I am trying to build a simple robot with. I am writing a library for this and also writing a simple code to test this. When I run this code, I get the error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.3 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno"

RobotTestDrive.cpp.o: In function `setup':
/Users/pawlak/RobotTestDrive.ino:5: undefined reference to `RobotVEXMotor::RobotVEXMotor(int)'
/Users/pawlak/RobotTestDrive.ino:6: undefined reference to `RobotVEXMotor::RobotVEXMotor(int)'
/Users/pawlak/RobotTestDrive.ino:8: undefined reference to `RobotVEXMotor::SetInvert(bool)'
/Users/pawlak/RobotTestDrive.ino:10: undefined reference to `RobotVEXMotor::SetPower(long)'
/Users/pawlak/RobotTestDrive.ino:11: undefined reference to `RobotVEXMotor::SetPower(long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

This is the program I am using:

```
#include </Users/pawlak/Documents/Arduino/libraries/VEX_Robot_Control/VEX_Robot_Control.h>

void setup() 
{
  RobotVEXMotor LeftMotor(11);
  RobotVEXMotor RightMotor(3);

  LeftMotor.SetInvert(true);

  LeftMotor.SetPower(1);
RightMotor.SetPower(1);
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

This is the .h file:

```
#ifndef VEX_Robot_Control_h
#define VEX_Robot_Control_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class RobotVEXMotor
{
    public:
        RobotVEXMotor(int pin);
        void SetPower(long power);
        void SetInvert(bool yn);
    private:
        int m_pin;
        int m_yn;
};

#endif
```

And this is the .cpp file:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "VEX_Robot_Control.h"


RobotVEXMotor::RobotVEXMotor(int pin)
{
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    m_pin = pin;
}

void RobotVEXMotor::SetPower(float power)
{
    analogWrite(pin, int((m_yn * power * 126) + 127));
}

void RobotVEXMotor::SetInvert(bool yn) //since motors are mirror to each other
{
    if(yn = true)
    {
        m_yn = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        m_yn = 1;
    }
}
```

I understand that this has been a topic that has appeared in the past; however, I can't seem to be able to fix the problem following the instructions on different threads.

Answer (score -1):

`#include`-ing the library's `.h` in your source isn't enough; you also need to tell the linker to include the binary code in your executable. Per https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries ,

> To use a library in a sketch, select it from Sketch > Import Library.